# Display InsertRow on the bottom of Telerik GridView

Tags: silverlight, gridview, telerik

The Telerik GridView for Silverlight includes the property ShowInsertRow. When you set this property to true the grid displays a special "Click here to add new item" row at the top of the grid below the header. Does anyone know how to display this special row at the bottom after the last data record?

Failing that, is it possible to add a fake row at the bottom that would do the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was able to make my own ContentTemplate that had the InsertRow below the data rows.